# Get zoomed-in images with the EarthExplorer API

Tags: python, api, usgs, earth-explorer

I've been using the landsatxplore library that provides a Python API for EarthExplorer. However, when I've been searching for scenes using code like this:

```
scenes = api.search(
    dataset='LANDSAT_ETM_C1',
    latitude=40.906,
    longitude=-73.810,
    start_date='2017-01-01',
    end_date='2019-01-01',
    max_cloud_cover=0.5,
)
```

the only scenes that have been returning are ones that encompass half of the northwest USA, like this:

[image]

When in reality I'm looking for images that show individual houses and roads, like this (direct from the EarthExplorer interactive map):

[image]

Its obviously technically possible to get images like the above, because EarthExplorer possesses these qualities of images, but none of the scenes that have been returning with my code have them. Is there a way, through the EarthExplorer API and landsatxplore, to get images that are zoomed in like this? Barring that, is there an API of some sort that, when given the coordinates of a location, will provide a similar image?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for services that can provide images with the same or slightly lesser zoom levels, as shown in the second image, of the entire world, or close to it, not just the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a little digging, I found an alternative to EarthExplorer called Mapbox. You can sign up and obtain an API access key very easily at [mapbox.com](https://mapbox.com). Once you've done so, you can use this code to download an image of the specified latitude and longitude:

```py
import math
import requests
import shutil

# Get the y tile value based on a latitude value
def latToTile(latDeg, zoom):
    latRadians = math.radians(latDeg)
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    return int((1.0 - math.asinh(math.tan(latRadians)) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)

# Get the x tile value based on a longitude value
def lonToTile(lonDeg, zoom):
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    return int((lonDeg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)

# Download an image for a specified location
def getImage(latitude, longitude, zoom, accessToken):
    url = ("https://api.mapbox.com/v4/" + "mapbox.satellite/" + str(zoom) + "/" + str(lonToTile(longitude, zoom)) +
           "/" + str(latToTile(latitude, zoom)) + "@2x.png?access_token=" + accessToken)

    imageName = "images/" + str(latitude) + "," + str(longitude) + ".png"

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(imageName, "wb") as image:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, image)
    del response
```

In this case, you should call the `getImage` function and, as arguments, pass it the latitude and longitude of the location you want to find, then a zoom level of 17, then your API key.

This code works by converting your latitude and longitude coordinates into tiles on a 2D grid, then using the `requests` module to download the image from the Mapbox API.